# Aspnetcore: how to publish loosely coupled projects?

Tags: asp.net-core, deployment

I have a solution with several loosely coupled components.
At publish-time, the components (and all their dependencies) should be copied to a (sub)folder of the main application.

Example:
My solution contains two projects:

- MainApp
- DAL

MainApp contains the main entry point of the application. DAL depends on some interfaces defined in MainApp and is loaded by MainApp at runtime. Note, however, that MainApp has no dependency to DAL. At publish-time, the output of DAL (and its dependencies) should be copied to the MainApp output folder, in order it to be available at run-time.

At compile time, addin projects (DAL, in this example) are copied to the main app's module, like this:

```
  <Target Name="MakeAddinsDirectories" AfterTargets="Build">
      <MakeDir Directories="$(MainAppAddinsDirectory)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CopyOutputFiles" AfterTargets="MakeAddinsDirectories">
      <Copy SourceFiles="@(AddinFiles)" DestinationFOlder="$(MainAppAddinsDirectory)" />
  </Target>
```

so, while debugging, they are available to the MainApp.

What is the best way to publish the add-ins (like DAL) to the MainApp?

Comment: There's no good way to do what you want, mostly because it's a horribly bad idea. You can't just arbitrarily "loosely couple" something. If MainApp depends on DAL, then that is a tight coupling, and there's nothing you can do about that. You should add a reference to DAL from MainApp and let everything happen naturally. A dependency is a dependency, you can't just wish it away.

Comment: @ChrisPratt : the dependency is in the opposite way: MainApp has several interfaces; DAL just implement them. There could be many projects implementing the same interfaces. They are discovered at run-time by MainAppe. I just want the implementation in DAL to be available.

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on new explanation:

I guess that you want to apply plugin model to add DAL libraries dynamically from a sub folder. So it requires you know some scripting. Basically, a idea is you use a MsBuild with PreBuildEvent to trigger `dotnet build -o {your sub path}` to force DotNet to build DAL project and copy to sub folder.

Edit your MainApp.csproj and add the node below

```
 <Project>
// Some xml nodes
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
     <Exec Command="dotnet build {your DAL path}/DAL.csproj -o {your sub path}" />
</Target>
</Project>
```

However, I don't know how big your solution is, but it is a few projects (under 5-6 projects), I recommend you to add reference all projects instead of using these scripting above. Why? Because it leads you to a complexity management.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking.

Comment: @JohnathanLe thanks! This is a "pull mode", in which MainApp "pulls" projects. I updated my question showing a "push mode", in which, at compile-time, add-ins copy themselves to the main project's output directory. This way the main project is not aware of add-ins. I got the idea, though. thanks!

Comment: So in this case, I thought you should prepare a Powershell/Bash script. In this script you want to declare a add-ins folder which contains all plugins as DAL(Ex: ** /AddIns/*.csproj) and then you loop these files with `dotnet build -o {sub path}`. Next you want to add `PreBuildEvent` in MainApp to trigger this script.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting isn't possible. If DAL has a dependency on MainApp, then MainApp *cannot* have a dependency on DAL, whether that dependency comes in at compile time or runtime. That would be a circular reference.

What you should do is move the interfaces out into a separate class library, which DAL would depend on instead of MainApp. Then MainApp can have a direct reference to DAL.